# yarn registry scopes - injecting scope name + %2f into the registry url

Tags: npm-install, yarn-workspaces

trying to setup yarn scoped registry using example [here](https://sergiodxa.com/articles/use-scoped-registry)

but the installer keeps appending scope name to the url.

### .yarnrc

`@myscope:registry" "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/npm/myco`

### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@myscope/web-components": "0.0.29",
```

#### `yarn install --verbose`

```
Performing "GET" request to "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/npm/myco/@myscope%2fweb-components  finished with status code 404.

verbose 1.176178875 Error: Couldn't find package "@myscope/web-components@0.0.29" required by "web@0.1.0" on the "npm" registry.".
```

so `@myscope%2f` is injected into the request address.

expcting
`https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/npm/myco/web-components`

getting
`https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/npm/myco/@myscope%2fweb-components`

```
yarn version 
1.22.19
```